# Multiple database handling in cscope

Tags: database, windows, vim, cscope

I have the following problem. I have a directory with project, let's assume:

```
C:\projects\handler
```

I also have a library that this project uses:

```
C:\projects\core_library
```

I use `cscope` to create the databases:

```
C:\projects\handler>C:\tools\cscope\cscope -R
C:\projects\core_library>C:\tools\cscope\cscope -R
```

Now in vim I change the directory:

```
:cd C:\projects\handler
```

And add the databases

```
:cs add cscope.out
:cs add C:\projects\core_library\cscope.out
```

Now the problem is that no files cannot be found from the core_library. This actually makes sense, as the path to the core_library should be preceded with "..\core_library" but it's not.

My question is: How can I precede the files in database (core_library) with "..\core_library"?

Comment: Why don't you create a single database in C:\projects\?

Comment: Because there are a lot of other directories that I don't want to include

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is here. In my case I should do:

```
:cs add C:\projects\core_library\cscope.out C:\projects\core_library
```